# C# assign click action for dynamic menuStrip items

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I'm building a program that relies on reading the SerialPorts available on a system and populating a menuStrip item.  I've been able to populate the menuStrip submenu but I am stuck on how to add a click event to the dynamically filled in list.  My code is below:

```
    public void getPorts()
    {
        int count = 0;
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach(string port in ports)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Serial Port " + port + " found!");
            ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(port);
            portMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(port);
            count += 1;
        }
    }
```

I feel like something needs to go into the `foreach` loop but I have been unable to locate it.  Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Just assign handler to each menu item which you are adding:

```
ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(port);
subItem.Click += MenuItem_Click;
// you should add menu item to some menu here
```

You can get item which was clicked in handler by casting event sender object to menu item type:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    var port = menuItem.Text;
    // ...
}
```

**Update** - adding items to `ToolStripDropDownButton`:

```
foreach(string port in ports)
{
    portMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(port).Click += MenuItem_Click; // see definition above
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried using it and added a simple MessageBox.Show in the MenuItem_Click, but it doesn't seem to work.  For example, my computer reports ports COM5, COM1, and COM11.  If I click on COM5, it doesn't product my message box.  I guess I'm missing something?

Comment: @Alex seems like you do. Make sure you are assigning event handler for each menu item `subItem.Click += MenuItem_Click;` and set a breakpoint in that method. Check if breakpoint will hit when you click on menu item

Comment: @SergeyBerezovsky Sorry I should have mentioned that I did add in the subItem.Click += MenuItem_Click code above as well.  Still doesn't work...

Edit: I added a breakpoint in the 'menuItem_Click' function and after clicking on the subitem added it does not trigger the breakpoint

Comment: @Alex that means you didn't assign event handler to menu item which you are actually clicking. Verify carefully which item you are clicking

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskly That's where I am stuck.  What I'm doing, at the moment, is I have a menuStrip item `portMenuItem` with no hard-coded subItems. The port lookup loop adds subItems to `portMenuItem`, which that works fine.  However, I do not know what it sames the created subItems...maybe I need to hardcode subItems that get renamed later via the sub?

Comment: @Alex sorry, but I don't understand what you are doing now. Code which you provided is not adding `subItems` anywhere. You are adding ports to drop down, but menu items are not used and not added anywhere

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskly I apologize if this is confusing, I'm new to C# and even doing a menustrip.  What I ultimately what to do is have my program scan the serial ports on a computer, which can be different from computer to computer.  After it does that, I want it to fill in a menu item that has the path "File -> COMM PORT -> COM1, COM2, etc" so the user can select the COM port.  Currently, I only have the "File -> COMM PORT" done, I thought I could dynamically add the COMs as they are found to form a submenu.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Alex but you have said before that you are clicking on `COM5`. And now you are saying that you have only `File -> COMM PORT` done. I don't understand that. Did you add menu items or not?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskly The `COM5` port was detected by my program after scanning the ports on my computer (accomplished by the line `string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();`.  What I want is for the program to go through the `string[]` array, add items based on the number of ports found, then assign click events to them.  Again, sorry if my original question was poorly worded.

Comment: @Alex I still don't understand how did you click `COM5` menu item if you don't have such menu item

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskly I figured out a different way because I realized the way I'm doing it now just doesn't work.  What I ended up doing was create subItems (i.e. `port0MenuItem`, `port1MenuItem`, etc.) and I change the name to the portID as the `GetPortNames` function returns ports.  Kind of clunky but it works.  Thanks again for your help and I'm sorry for all of the confusion.

Comment: @Alex see update how to add items to menu dropdown button and subscribe each to event